# What's the noun based on the adverb 'deliberately'?

Tags: nouns, word-formation

If I do something with a great sense of purpose, if I do it extremely... intentionally and deliberately. I do it with... deliberalcy? Deliberacy? My searches have returned nothing.

Comment: You do it with *deliberation*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use deliberation but, depending on the context, it may be more appropriate to use 'deliberateness'.

> **deliberateness**
>
> Pronunciation: /dəˈlɪbərətnəs/
>
> noun
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> You can see the deliberateness with which the scholar seeks his
>   material after he gets going, but a poet never lives in that way at
>   all.
>
> Not only, then, does materialist evolutionary theory fail to deliver
>   knowledge, truth, deliberateness and agency, but they are of little or
>   no evolutionary value.
>
> It is has a sense of heightened unreality, a deliberateness that gives
>   the characters depth despite occasionally too-smooth dialogue.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deliberate)

Comment: This is to disambiguate from the other sense of *deliberation,* when one is deliberating over something, or weighing something up. Some sentences (particularly the first above) need the distinction. "Doing something *with deliberation"* doesn't normally impute that though.